# Android App published with limited countries and tester is outside of that countries

Tags: android, google-play, publish, beta, beta-testing

My current scenario:

- I launched app with 2 country named XX and YY. The app's tester are from ZZ country.
- App is launched in Beta Channel in Google play developer console
- We created Close Beta testing and added those all user's email address who are from ZZ country
- If we send APK to user by email, then they can download and install and test it as well in his device.
- if we send opt-in URL and they can not download APP from url, Google play shows "This app is incompatible with your device." message in browser and "This item is not available in your country" message in Googleplay app in android device

So is there any possibilities that we can setup such environment ?

Comment: As for this "This app is incompatible with your device"  message, Which device they are using to test?

Comment: As far as it's closed beta testing you can lauch app in zz contry aslo. anyway it will be downloadable to those people whose email has been added in the testers list

Comment: do only one thing create a new play store account(gmail account) for like your XX and XY country then say to your tester to use these account ... for after done all these steps your tester easily download your app from play store

Comment: @Raghavendra, Moto G(2nd Generation). As i mentioned in my question APK works fine, if i download it by email. then Why google play store show this erro ?

Comment: @indramurari App will have continuous development and integration. After completing minimal functionalities, we will move it to production. So in this case, we can not test it outside from XX & YY, Correct ?

If we are willing to test this app by tester who are outside XX & YY, then is there any possible way to do that ?